# Javascript to edit table rows

Tags: javascript, mysql, edit

I need help with a feature for my site. I just cant make the script work.
I have this site:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXG3s.jpg
As you can see, there is one "*Edit*" button for each row. The goal here is that when the user press one of those, the row gets editable (except for the subject name) and the button changes to "*Save*". Then the user can edit all he wants and save it. When he clicks "*Save*" I get all fields that were changed and update via SQL query.
PS:The number of rows is undefined because the user can input as many rows as he wants.

So I thought in some script like this:

```
var button = document.getElementByClassName("clicker");
var buttonclicked = function(){
    button.textContent = "Save"; //And things get editable};
button.addEventListener("click", buttonclicked);
```

But this wont work because *var button* is an array of buttons, and the *addEventListener* wont work with that...
What can I do to solve this?

This is the HTML generating the table: (Might be a little bit messy)

```
<?php $i = 0;?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
    <tr class="d1">
        <td><?php echo $row["subject"] ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php 
                if($row["G1"] != -1)
                    echo $row["G1"];      
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php 
                if($row["G2"] != -1)
                    echo $row["G2"];      
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php 
                if($row["G3"] != -1)
                    echo $row["G3"];      
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php 
                if($row["G4"] != -1)
                    echo $row["G4"];      
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php 
                $round = round($row["normal"],2);
                echo $round;
            ?>
        </td>
        <td><?= $row["creditos"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["criteria"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo "<button id = clicker.$i>Edit</button>"; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Give each button a unique id, and then use `getElemenetById`. Number them?

Comment: I cant do that because, as I said, I dont know how many edit buttons there will be, because the user can create rows.
The closest I got to that was give the buttons a variable ID, unsing php to increase a counter. But then I dont know how to call them all in one function in the script.
I am going to post the HTML that is generating the table:

Comment: You do know - You can count them. Have the page keep a running total. You can give each new row a unique number.

Comment: Like I do in the last "<td>" of this HTML? Then how can I make the script work for all of them in the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign to each button via `for` loop:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("clicker");

var buttonclicked = function(e){
    e.target.textContent = "Save"; //And things get editable};

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', buttonclicked);
}
```

Also notice that I'm working on `e.target` in the `buttonclicked` function, rather than `button`, so that we get the right button each time.

The `e` is the [event object](http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object) that holds information about the `onclick` event. If you look at the `buttonclicked` variable you see it's assigned `function(e)` now instead of just `function()`.

Comment: Pretty awsome dude! I was trying to use a for loop, but I didnt really know which lines should be inside of it...

Comment: Can you explain me what is that "e" and that line: "e.target"? I am not verry good with php and have not yet learned it

Comment: That's part of javascript. If you look at the `buttonclicked` variable you see it's assigned `function(e)` now instead of just `function()`. The `e` is the [event object](http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object) that holds information about the `onclick` event.